# How to set SOLine SiteID -- Internally it is an Int but gets displayed as String in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am customizing SOOrderEntry. When a new SOLine is added, I want to fill in the SiteID field with the User's Default Warehouse.

The challenge is that the SiteID field in the SQL database is an Int. But, what is displayed for the user is actually DefaultBranchCD, which is a string. DefaultBranchCD is not part of the row, so I cannot set it.

[image: Inspector Window]

I have the value of SiteID, and the Value of DefaultBranchCD -- but I cannot put the DefaultBranchCD in the SiteID field (even though, apparently, the ERP can somehow.)

What am I missing?

Simple Code so far:

```
        try
        {
            var curUsr = base.Base.Accessinfo.UserID;
            var usrBranchID = UserPreferences.PK.Find(e.Cache.Graph, curUsr).DefBranchID;
            var DefaultBranchCD = INSite.PK.Find(e.Cache.Graph, usrBranchID).SiteCD;
            row.SiteID = usrBranchID;
            
        }
        catch { }
```

This puts the SiteID (eg 24) in the field, and not the value the user is expecting to see (eg "1-MILFORD")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acumatica should automatically mask the int key value SiteID with the descriptive value SiteCD.  Because the OP was setting the value after the cache was updated (RowUpdated), the system didn't the display the descriptive value.  Changing the event to RowInserting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Acumatica's code, Site is the term that the UI translates as Warehouse.  SiteID is the Warehouse key and the text value that is displayed for the key is the SiteCD.  These values should be sourced from the table INSite.

Comment: Patrick, I think you misunderstand my question, I know how to get the value from INSite (see code above) My question is, once I have it, how do I USE it?  SiteCD is not a field that is available to me in the row of SOLine. What they list in Inspector is SiteID, but what they display to the user is SiteCD. How do I do that?

Comment: Acumatica should automatically display the SiteCD that corresponds to the SiteID

Comment: OK, it wasn't doing it, but I moved my code from Events.RowUpdated<SOLine> to _(Events.RowInserting<SOLine> e), and now it does operate correctly. If you want to put together an answer, I'll select it as correct. If not, LMK and I'll just close this out. Thanks!